# Causing A Snowstorm

Tags: aliens, environment, super-powers, weather, wind

Okay, so I have a humanoid alien villain who can cause massive windstorms. She is capable of moving at Mach speeds, and can rotate her arms and legs really fast, and stands at about 2.06 m tall, and weighs 105.8 kg. Via her rotations, she creates powerful winds that let her fly and blow foes away. And she needs to stir up the winds of a snowy, circular area of a radius of 1 mile (1.6 km) up to 56 km/h (15.5 m/s) for let's say, 10 minutes. How fast will she need to move around in order to do that? She can either be spinning in one spot, or going round and round in circles.

Comment: Humanoid like, totally comparable to a human, or does she have palms instead of hands for instance? Are personal equipments authorized (arm wings...)?

Comment: Air weighs about 1.29 kg per cubic meter.  Regular old pi-r-squared tells us the area of the 1.6 km circle is 8,042,477 square meters and, for a snowstorm, we'd want it to extend to an altitude of 100m.  So, the super-villain is pushing around 1,037,480 metric tons of air around (about 2 fully loaded oil supertankers of mass).   For something as small as a 2m tall humanoid, we're talking something like cometary reentry speeds (Mach 25+) to create a shockwave pushing around that much air.   If it has to take, say, less than a minute to create the storm, let's say Mach 100, maybe even Mach 200.

Comment: Simple answer, she can't.  She's essentially a small helicopter, like the Robinson R-22 :-)

Comment: Similarly, let's assume that this super-villain spinning  is 10 times as effective as a 8" desk fan: 17.7 cubic meters/sec flow at 2 m/s velocity when spinning at 1200 rpm (sourced from https://www.hunker.com/13407187/how-to-calculate-cfm-from-rpms).  To move 804,247,700 cubic meters of air at 15 meters per second would require the super-villain to spin at 40.7 billion RPM.  Making the super-villain 10,000,000x more powerful than a desk fan still leaves us at 40.7 million RPM.

Comment: (Continued) Note that the numbers above aren't really meaningful, let alone correct, since the formulas used are being used way, way outside of the range where they give valid results. They are only intended to give a rough idea of the magnitudes involved so that the super-villain's powers can be adjusted to give you the capability and effect that you want.

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: Math error in what I said above: what I should've said was "Making the super-villain 10,000,000x more powerful than a desk fan still leaves them spinning at 40,700 RPM."
Also, @KeizerHarm  It's not really an answer to what the querent is asking since the results aren't truly correct.  At best it's a hint or a launching point for the ideas of others.

Comment: Also worth noting, borrowing from @GrumpyYoungMan's back-of-the-envelope stuff - getting that much air moving in a hurry is going to generate a _lot_ of heat.  So it won't be a snowstorm, either.

Comment: jdunlop, I forgot to say that she can chill her surroundings to temperatures comparable to liquid nitrogen. That way, she can prevent the snow from melting.

Comment: She must have really spectacular skin-care routine to keep it from being burned, frozen, or eroded away by use of her superpower. Selling that skin-care secret might be a more worthwhile effort than menacing folks.

Comment: user535733, keep in mind that she's an alien whose got a body that already resists arctic temperatures, and her natural abilities were enhanced, such as her tissue's endurance and regeneration. But yeah, I can see where you're coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot, GrumpyYoungMan. You could have posted your findings as an answer, so why the heck did you have to make it a set of comments instead of just one answer? Anyways, here it is. Our character acts like a giant fan with four smaller fans attached to her, and the air column is 100 m tall. Now, we will assume that she's spinning around an radius equivalent to half of the storm's radius, so the radius of the air column is 801 m. That means that the volume of the column is 202 million m^3. The rotational velocity would have to be 10.175 billion rpm, or about 170 MHz. That is over three times the speed of light, so she can't be doing that.

However, we can increase her power output to ten million times that of a desk fan, which would mean that her frequency would be 17 Hz. That's the bare minimum. We can easily put her speed at Mach 100, and see the conditions of the shockwaves. Using the formulas found here (https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/normal.html), I can calculate that if she were to chill the air around her to 78 K, and the initial pressure at 101 kPa, the shockwaves she generates have pressures of up to 128 thousand atm, which is greater than the bottom of the sea. And the temperatures would be comparable to the Butterfly Nebula, but by the time the air decompresses, it will cool back down, even to temperatures low enough to solidify the air.

However, this will sublime the snow, and the character will have to later fly up to cool down the air, and make it snow (being in an already-cold location definitely helps). The telltale signs would be scorch marks on the ground. So, creating the snowstorm won't be instantaneous, and would require a day or two of prep.

Comment: So it wouldn't so much "create a snowstorm" as "destroy the country around where she was trying to make a snowstorm".