# How fast should one be running to start a tornado?

Tags: science-based, super-powers

Running so fast that it creates a tornado is used in some fighting stories, and I want to recreate that feat. The on running can have ridiculous speed, and we can have multiple people running at once if necessary.

Is it possible to create a tornado just by running really fast? If yes, what speed is needed?

Comment: This is kind of similar to https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/191772/causing-a-snowstorm so looking at the responses there may be helpful as well.

Answer (score 9):

To start an actual tornado you would need to create the appropriate [local conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tornadogenesis)

> Classical tornadoes are supercellular tornadoes, which have a recognizable pattern of formation. The cycle begins when a strong thunderstorm develops a rotating mesocyclone a few miles up in the atmosphere. As rainfall in the storm increases, it drags with it an area of quickly descending air known as the rear flank downdraft (RFD). This downdraft accelerates as it approaches the ground, and drags the rotating mesocyclone towards the ground with it. Storm relative helicity (SRH) has been shown to play a role in tornado development and strength. SRH is horizontal vorticity that is parallel to the inflow of the storm and is tilted upwards when it is taken up by the updraft, thus creating vertical vorticity.
>
> As the mesocyclone lowers below the cloud base, it begins to take in cool, moist air from the downdraft region of the storm. This convergence of warm air in the updraft, and this cool air, causes a rotating wall cloud to form.

I think it's obvious that no amount of running characters can set that up.

Some years ago I wanted to know how to determine the clean zone where to install a wind turbine in an area with buildings, and a colleague told me that a rule of thumb for estimating the extension of the zone of disturbed flow behind an obstacle of height H was to consider a volume of max height 2H and extending for 10H. Following that rule of thumb even an NBA player running at full speed won't disturb more than 5 meters high of air. It will never reach few miles high in the atmosphere.

An alternative approach to show that it is impossible is to consider the energy involved. Let's say that a tornado releases the same amount of energy of a [severe thunderstorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_%28energy%29), that is $10^{15}$ J. A 100 kg person would need to run at 2% of the speed of light to have that energy, and would burn as a consequence of the drag well before producing a tornado.

What you are probably looking for is the formation of [Von Karman vortexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A1rm%C3%A1n_vortex_street) in the trail of the running character.

[image: von Karman vortex]

> In fluid dynamics, a Kármán vortex street (or a von Kármán vortex street) is a repeating pattern of swirling vortices, caused by a process known as vortex shedding, which is responsible for the unsteady separation of flow of a fluid around blunt bodies.
>
> A vortex street will form only at a certain range of flow velocities, specified by a range of Reynolds numbers (Re), typically above a limiting Re value of about 90. The (global) Reynolds number for a flow is a measure of the ratio of inertial to viscous forces in the flow of a fluid around a body or in a channel, and may be defined as a nondimensional parameter of the global speed of the whole fluid flow:
>
> $Re_L=$$UL \over \nu_0$
>
> where:
>
> $U$ = the free stream flow speed, which is the original global flow parameter, i.e. the target to be non-dimensionalised.
>
> $L$ = a characteristic length parameter of the body or channel
>
> $\nu_0$ = the free stream kinematic viscosity parameter of the fluid

An empiric way to check at which velocity this happens is to check when, holding a flag, it start to flap around: at that moment it is reacting to the vortexes your body is producing. If I remember correctly out of experience, that happens around 30 km/h already.

Comment: What if the person in question is running in a circle faster than the speed of sound, and is repeatedly impacting their own shock wave? I'm pretty sure that this question is about The Flash.

Comment: @nick012000 it makes a bad noise and subjects the runner to additional stress, but other than that, nothing additionally interesting. This sort of thing happened with old-school high performance aircraft engines where the tips of the blades could exceed the speed of sound.

Answer (score 4):

The current land-speed record is ~1224km/h, achieved over a distance of 1km. Experimental maglev trains have managed peak speeds of 500km/h over distances of ~30km. Even more conventional trains on steel rails can sustain speeds of over 300km/h whilst providing a passenger service. Special trains had similar performance going back as far as the 50s.

None of these things produce tornadoes, and they're pretty big, heavy and fast.

The closest anything comes to a tornado generated by a moving object are wing tip vortices on fixed-wing aircraft:

[image: Wake Turbulence study at Wallops Island in 1990]

These are horizontal, and are found in the flight paths of aircraft. They can persist for a surprisingly long time, and are powerful enough to flip smaller aircraft over which has lead to a depressing number of fatalities. They are not anywhere near as swiftly rotating or as destructive as an actual tornado. Here's some analysis of of a small-*ish* aircraft (an [Antonov AN-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonov_An-2)) flipping a much smaller aircraft on takeoff, resulting in a fatal crash: [Wake turbulence hazard analysis for a general aviation accident](http://www.dglr.de/publikationen/2014/340177.pdf).

If you carried a wing big enough to lift a small passenger aircraft (so at least 15m span) and ran at takeoff speed (50-100km/h+, depending), you could produce a strong enough vortex to flip light aircraft and maybe knock people off their feet.

I can't help feel that if you were moving that fast, hitting people with the wing would be the most effective way to take them out of the fight.

---

Another alternative might perhaps be to create a [fire devil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_whirl)

[image: Fire devil]

If large enough these could have [tornado-like destructive power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firestorm), but I feel like that might be overshadowed by the *enormous super hot inferno* driving them. A bit more magic/pyrokinetic rather in flavour, too.